# Symfony3 double list widget

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to create a form that contains two lists of the users:

ListA contains all available users

ListB contains the users from selected entity

[image]

But I can not find any information about how can I create this widget. And I would ask you about the best approach which can be used to create this widget.

Answer (score 0):

For a form like this you need a mix from a Symfony form, plain HTML and Javascript.

The first question is which Data do you need to process in your application if a user hits the Submit button? The form fields that hold the data that you need to process are the fields that you should add to your formType class. All the other dropdowns, links, buttons and whatever more should be build with Twig/HTML. Then you need to apply Javascript to let something happen when the user clicks a button or select an item.

For example on the left pane holding all users, you can render it easily with a for loop in twig. You dont need that list as an form field because you are not interested in a list of all users.